# PHP Header (location: Mailto.. ) Issue on windows 7 Pro after last update

Tags: php, windows, mailto

Since the last update on windows 7, a lot of clients are complaining that they got following error:

---

Corrupted Content Error

### The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because an error in the data transmission was detected.

when they run a PHP script which executes following PHP (sample) script:

```
<?php
    header ('Location: mailto:xx@example.de?subject=hello&body=test' ); 
?>
```

Does anybody know a php workaround for this issue? unfortunately I can´t asked tons of web users to change their system.

Regards from Germany

Comment: Are they trying to redirect after sending an email?

Comment: No, they just run the mentioned script

Comment: I think it happens when there are multiple headers, in that case you must force the second header. So if they have to redirect, they have to add false to the next argument, say after that mail header they want to redirect then the code should be `header('Location: somewhere.php', false');`

Comment: I know, but there is only one header, see script example.

Comment: Have you tried `exit();` after the header?

Comment: I Just did, No Change....

Comment: After adding Exit(); there was no Change

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed some weird stuff when trying to use php Location headers to redirect to mailto url.  In my case, it would fail in IE (not Chrome) when certain characters were in the subject (for instance "Subject=RE: ABC", the colon would cause IE to barf.  To get around the issue, I replaced the PHP location redirect:

```
header ('Location: mailto:xx@example.de?subject=hello&body=test' );
```

with the javascritp equivalent:

```
echo '<SCRIPT>window.location="mailto:xx@example.de?subject=hello&body=test";</SCRIPT>');
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid an empty window (tab, page) after your mail handler is done, you can add a second `header ("Location ...");` to redirect to your main page, in that case here `index.php`:

```php
<?php
    header ("Location: mailto:xx@example.de", false);
    header ("Location: index.php");
    exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

During Testing I found out that the mailto header was not executed, when I use two headers! See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57862546/10655742. So I found a better solution.

Use `_self` instead of `blank` in the html file

```html
<a href="mailto-handler.php" target="_self" rel="noopener noreferrer"></a>
```

Mailto-Handler.php

```php
<?php
    header ("Location: mailto:xx@example.de");
    exit();
?>
```